# Calling a function before it's declared

Tags: javascript

I have some code near the top of my file like this:

```
var my12proddate = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('my12prodDate'));
var mytstprod = my12proddate[0];
if (mytstprod == null) {
    myupdatedproddate();
}
```

And further down in the code is this:

```
var num = size;

function myupdatedproddate() {          
    for (var a = 0; a < num; a++) {
        var dt = new Date(startmothnyear);
        dt.setMonth(dt.getMonth() - a);
        var newww = dt.toString()
        var monthNum = months[newww.substring(4, 7).toLowerCase()];
        var yearNum = newww.substring(24, 28);
        var monthandyearNum = monthNum + "/" + yearNum;
        monthsupdated[a] = monthandyearNum;

    }
}
```

When I run this script it gives me an `myupdatedproddate is undefined` error.

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Please provide a **complete** example. We can't really do much with *pieces* of code, especially since this seems to be a code organization problem.

Comment: Is there any way to achieve it this way ?

Comment: @War10ck: It shouldn't matter. As Felix suggested, we need to see the complete example.

Comment: This simply [can't happen](http://jsfiddle.net/Zj9bT/). Your problem is somewhere else

Comment: please provide jsfiddle.

Comment: This should actually work fine, in principle, due to hoisting. My guess is that your function is actually out of scope and you don't realize it.

Comment: Is this in the same js file? Is your `myupdateproddate` function nested inside some other function?

Comment: Yes it can be because it is very long js file it may be out of scope

Comment: File length doesn't impact scope. Longer files might be more difficult to maintain, but that's not something we can help you with.

Comment: Always fun when a question is posted by `/user[0-9]*/g`

Comment: The only think I can think of is that "further" means "in another script tag supposed to be loaded after this one"

Comment: it is not out of score error I just tested it  using another function in a scope but it gives me same error

Answer (score 3):

In the normal course of things, that's fine, because you're using a function *declaration*. This works, for instance:

```
foo();

function foo() {
    console.log("Hi there");
}
```

Function declarations are processed upon entry to the scope, *before* any step-by-step code is executed, as long as they're in the same *code compilation unit* (on browsers, that's a `script` element).

So if it's not working, that tells us that the function is declared in a different *scope* than the code in which it's called, or in a different code compilation unit.

This fails, for instance:

```
foo();

$(document).ready(function() {   
    function foo() {
        console.log("Hi there");
    }
});
```

...because `foo` is contained within the function we're giving to `ready`, so it doesn't exist outside of it, and we can't call it.

Similarly, this fails:

```
<script>
    foo();
</script>
<script>
    function foo() {
        console.log("Hi there");
    }
</script>
```

...because the declaration is in a code compilation unit *after* the one where we tried to use it, so it doesn't exist yet when we try to use it.

So you'll want to look at where your function is declared, and where you're using it, and make sure you're only using it from a place that can actually see it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find if you add the missing semicolon below it should work if everything else you say is as it is.

```
var num = size;

    function myupdatedproddate() {          
        for (var a = 0; a < num; a++) {
            var dt = new Date(startmothnyear);
            dt.setMonth(dt.getMonth() - a);
            var newww = dt.toString(); // <--- add this here
            var monthNum = months[newww.substring(4, 7).toLowerCase()];
            var yearNum = newww.substring(24, 28);
            var monthandyearNum = monthNum + "/" + yearNum;
            monthsupdated[a] = monthandyearNum;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I just noticed  I don't need this code in my js file any more

```
var my12proddate = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('my12prodDate'));
```

I commented it out and it worked .

Thanks for your effort..

Comment: Did you add the semi-colon as I mentioned? Otherwise it surely can't work!

Comment: Yes. the reason is not that , because it is not even go in to the function.i just answered the question , please upvoe it and click as a answer.

Comment: First , this is nota  stupid question , lets assume it is a stupid question but your answer is far far way from the solution so does this make you stupid ?  I guess so . I kindly asked you , I didn't urge you , I answered your commend kindly ..why so serious ?

Comment: The reason i asked you to do that , the question is solved so people will see the  green check there and won't spend their time on it , but  somehow it just pissed you of  and you downvote , my account was already abput the block why did you do that ? , i wasn't expecting this kind of action from you ,  you really felt me sad

Comment: How could I know this ,  I just encountered with an error and shared it on stack overflow but I got some help  at least I tried what they asked me to do to resolve the issue ,they didn't waste their time actually they helped me to resolve the issue ,different strokes for different folks , you know. I learned  a lot of thisngs from their comments . It is not wasting , I am appreciate them and to you also . This was what I thought but then you came out with this comment and downvote my question and answer and it is locked , my account is locked because of you bro . This is what I felt sad.

Comment: The reason your account is locked (I'm guessing) is because 3 different people have voted to close the question.  Up and down votes are part of the process!  I don't have any power or inclination to lock your account.  You said *i just answered the question* when your question was *When I run this script it gives me an myupdatedproddate is undefined error.

Why am I getting this error?* and then told people to `upvote` and `accept` as the answer which is not correct no matter how it makes you feel!

Comment: Yeah cool, please don't be disheartened! Just next time you could *notice* that you don't need a line of code before you post! Glad you got it working in anycase.